# How do you use htaccess to redirect requests to a folder to a new subdomain?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am moving an application from a folder off the root, to a subdomain. So I need requests to `website.com/folder` to redirect to `folder.website.com`. Below is what I tried, but it adds the original folder to the URL. For example, it does `folder.website.com/folder/login`, but what I need is `folder.website.com/login`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ https://folder.website.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need this rule to only be applied to the folder route, then give the following a try **replacing** the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ https://folder.website.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

**WITH**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com$1 [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/(.*)$ https://folder.website.com/$1
```

You may already have the first 2 lines added.

Comment: Should I add this rule or replace the current one?

Comment: Replace the current one.

Comment: When I type 'folder.website.com' it redirects me to 'folder.webiste.com/folder (same as before).

Comment: I think it's working now! I haven't been able to test the entire application yet, but I'll be sure to mark as solved when I confirm. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewM did it work in the whole application? If yes, can you please accept this as an answer 